# Haskell foldable instance for data tree

Tags: haskell, instance

Trying to make a foldable instance for a data tree with the following code:

```
data Rose a = a :> [Rose a]
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Foldable Rose where
    fold (a:>b) =  a <> (map fold b)
```

However this code is not working, the error it produces:

```
Could not deduce <m ~ [m]>
from the context <Monoid m>
  bount by the type signature for fold :: Monoid m => Rose m -> m
...
In the return type of a call of 'map'
...
```

Does anyone know why/how to make it work?

Comment: «is not working» is not really useful. Does it not typecheck? What's the error message then? Or does it produce the wrong result? On what input?

Comment: Edited my post with the error message I'm getting

Comment: Do you understand what the error message says? If you read it slowly, I bet you'll know how to fix your problem. If not, you should also say which part of the error you don't understand.

Comment: I would recommend to implement `foldMap` when implementing `Foldable`. `foldMap` implementations have a regular shape, that you'll start to notice when you do a few of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write `fold b`, you're using the `Foldable` instance for lists. So the `fold` folds a list of monoidal values to a single value. The type of this monoidal value happens to be `Rose a` (that's what your list consists of). But that's probably not what you want.

Try to use `foldMap fold` instead of `fold` there. This way you first fold every individual `Rose a` in the list, and then fold the results together.